# Error 404 When trying to POST to plugin Controller action

Tags: ajax, controller, jquery

Before I dive into my problem, I do want to mention that I **did** do my due diligence and spent the last two days researching this problem, to no avail, so here it goes:

So I'm getting the following error when trying to load an action method from the controller: `Unable to resolve the request "ecaApi/main/doGeocodeRequest".` I get this error if I try and navigate directly to it, e.g. domain.com/actions/ecaApi/main/doGeocodeRequest

The AJAX request below also generates a 404.

**File Structure:**

```
- craft/plugins
  - ecaapi
    - controllers
      --EcaApi_MainController.php
    --EcaApiPlugin.php
```

**EcaApi_MainController.php**

```
 namespace Craft;

    class EcaApi_MainController extends BaseController
    {
        protected $allowAnonymous = true;

        public function actionDoGeocodeRequest() {
            //.....
            $this->returnJson($result);
        }
    }
```

**JS ajax call to the action method**

```
    var data = {
        address: "{{ event.event_location }}"
    };
    data[csrfTokenName] = csrfTokenValue;
    data['action'] = 'ecaApi/main/doGeocodeRequest';
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/",
        data: data
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            markers[{{ event.id }}] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, data.results[0].geometry.location.lng),
                map: map,
                {% if mapSettings.mapIcon %}
                icon: mapMarkerIcon,
                {% endif %}
                title: "{{ event.title }}"
            });
            var content = '<a href="{{ event.url|replace({'http://': 'https://'}) }}">{{ event.title }}</a>';
            var window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: content
            });
            markers[{{ event.id }}].addListener('click', function () {
                window.open(map, markers[{{ event.id }}]);
            });

        });
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been pulling out my hair for days over this.

Comment: "Unable to resolve the request "ecaApi/main/test". Was that the actual error or was it "Unable to resolve the request "ecaApi/main/doGeocodeRequest"? Not seeing a controller action named test in your example.

Comment: @BradBell I clarified that part, pasted the wrong error!

Comment: Your `EcaApiPlugin.php` file has a class name of `EcaApiPlugin`?

Comment: @BradBell Yes indeed!

Comment: Hrm... my gut says it's some silly case sensitivity issue, but I'm not seeing it from the example. Couldn't hurt to generate the boilerplate plugin code from https://pluginfactory.io/ to help rule that out.

Comment: @BradBell We are getting somewhere! I generated the skeletal plugin as suggested, and for the first time it actually appeared in my plugins list. I was also able to log a "Hello World" to the plugin's log file, so it seems to be working! Im going to re-write the guts of my original controller tonight and lets see what happens. 

Im curious to see what changed in the structure/files to make it wake up and see my plugin, time to pull up BeyondCompare :) 

Thanks!

Comment: Beyond Compare is the best! Be sure and add an official answer once you get to the bottom of it in case it ends up helping someone in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so thanks to @BradBell's suggestion, I regenerated the skeleton of my plugin and it's controller using [pluginfactory.io](http://pluginfactory.io) and it now magically works! Still not sure exactly what the difference was, but it does its job now!